# How to go from elliptic coordinates back to cartesian?

Tags: coordinate-systems, elliptic-functions

I know that the transform form cartesian to elliptical is

$x=a \cosh \mu \cos \nu; \;\;\;\; y=a \sinh \mu \sin \nu$

How do I go back to cartesian if I have an expression in elliptical, meaning that I need the relations

$\mu = f(x,y);\;\;\;\nu=g(x,y)$?

Comment: Wikipedia says that we need to use a multifunction. See [this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Elliptic_coordinate_system#Alternative_definition)

Comment: Yes, because it involves trigonometric functions. But Wiki does not provide the explicit transformation.

Comment: see here [link] https://www.researchgate.net/publication/309803947_A_Note_on_Elliptic_Coordinates

Comment: @serg_1 thanks a lot!

Comment: @serg_1: I find it quite incredible that this is accepted for publication in a scientific journal in 2017! Surely already Euler (who invented elliptic coordinates) knew the inverse transformation; after all, it's just a matter of solving a quadratic equation. (For Jacobi ellipsoidal coordinates in $\mathbf{R}^n$ it's a different thing, since then one would need to find the roots of higher-degree polynomials.)

Comment: @Hans Lundmark it is published in an applied physics journal and looks very comprehensible, comparing to all the rest that I have seen. When engineers and scientists use mathematics, they often need just a ready-to-go relation, which works most of the times, not how-to-get-it type of answer with n iff-s.